# counting column values based on strings

Tags: python, pandas

I have two columns the first one has strings either YES or NO and the other one has numeric value.
I want to create a new column its values are based on multiply values in the second column.

- Neglect the rows with YES that follow the first YES
- Neglect the rows with NO that follow the first NO
- Multiply the first YES with the first NO.

Actual data frame

```
COL1 =['YES','YES','NO','YES','YES','YES','YES','NO','YES','YES','NO',]
COL2 = [1,2,6,3,5,4,7,1,7,2,2]
```

---

Desired dataFrame

```
   |COL1|COL2|COL3|

    |YES|1|0|
    |YES|2|0|
    |NO|6|6|
    |YES|3|18|
    |YES|5|1|
    |YES|4|1|
    |YES|7|1|
    |NO|1|3|
    |YES|7|7|
    |YES|2|1|
    |NO|2|14|
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is your data structure:

```
data=[['yes', 1], ['yes','2'], ...]
```

let `last` equal the un-ignored data, in this case data[0] for the first 'yes'.

```
while last[0] == data[index][0]:
    data[index].append(0)
    index++
```

To solve the multiplication, replace `append(0)` with `append(last[1] * data[index][1])` and continue to the end index reaches the end of the data.

And since there seems to be some differences with your first 2 'yes' and the values of '1', the flag shouldn't be hard to throw in a 'previous' flag as well.